# syntax error: unexpected token < after replace controller in AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I use the sample of Auth0 examples AngularJS. I need to rewrite this sample and replace the controllers js file to a folder - controllers. But after doing that  I get an error: syntax error: unexpected token <
I figure out that it is may server problem
server configuration on node. js is :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname +  '/'));


app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const server = app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);  
});
```

What problem of this server? Thank you.

Comment: If you used to fetch your JS files from the root directory (`/myController.js`) and now you have these files in a directory, then you need to change the way `express.static` looks for these files. That or have your front-end properly request `/controllers/myController.js` instead of `/myController.js`.

Comment: Many thanks to you, this solution solve my problem